# How to install LineageOS on the Fairphone 3+

Tags: lineageos, side-loading, fairphone-3

This is my third attempt to install LineageOS (I've tried already with two other apparently supported devices, to no avail). I'm close to giving up. So I'll try to be as clear as possible.

- I'm very comfortable using the Linux command line (I use it every day at work). My laptop has Fedora installed on it.
- I have no "technical" experience with Android. My only experience is just using it as any other "non-technical" user would do.
- I have a brand new Fairphone 3+ to which I want to install the latest LineageOS. The Fairphone 3+ is listed in the [official list](https://wiki.lineageos.org/devices/#fairphone) of supported devices.

I followed the instructions mentioned [here](https://wiki.lineageos.org/devices/FP3/install). I enabled USB debugging and unlocked the  bootloader successfully. Then I went ahead and tried to flash the latest Lineage Recovery image (got it from [here](https://download.lineageos.org/FP3)), when I encountered the first problem:

```
$ sudo platform-tools/fastboot flash boot lineage-18.1-20211213-recovery-FP3.img
fastboot: error: boot partition is smaller than boot image
```

The first option that came to my mind was to use TWRP because I know the image size of TWRP is smaller, but then I saw the warning at the end of [this page](https://support.fairphone.com/hc/en-us/articles/360048646311-Manage-the-bootloader-of-your-FP3-FP3-) that says that "Fairphone does not support the use of the TWRP". So I abandoned the idea of using TWRP. Then I read [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/LineageOS/comments/n0k6sn/fairphone_3_fastboot_error_boot_partition_is/) that I should try to flash to `boot_a` or `boot_b` instead (no idea what that means). So I did:

```
$ sudo platform-tools/fastboot flash boot_a lineage-18.1-20211213-recovery-FP3.img
Sending 'boot_a' (65536 KB)                        OKAY [  2.194s]
Writing 'boot_a'                                   OKAY [  0.629s]
Finished. Total time: 2.953s
```

After that I went ahead and booted into recovery. I was surprised that it worked, but it did and I saw the Lineage Recovery menu. I did the mentioned factory reset successfully. But I got a problem during sideload:

```
$ sudo platform-tools/adb sideload lineage-18.1-20211213-nightly-FP3-signed.zip 
adb: failed to read command: Success
```

I noticed at the bottom of the phone's screen the following text:

```
Now send the package you want to apply
to the device with "adb sideload <filename>"...
```

But when I executed the actual `adb sideload ...` command no text was appended to the phone's screen.

Many sites mention that if the sideload stops at 47% and shows the `failed to read command: Success` message it means that it was in fact successful. But in my case there is no percentage at all. It seems as if the transfer doesn't even take place. Anyway, if a boot the phone normally I still boot into the "original" (or "factory") Android, not into LineageOS. So clearly the sideloading is not successful.

What am I doing wrong? Is this problem maybe related to the first one (that the Lineage Recovery image was too big for the boot partition)?

I'm slowly getting the feeling that the world of Android hacking (in the sense of just playing around) in general and of LineageOS in particular is just impenetrable and made just for a very few lucky geniuses.

Comment: I'm not really familiar with Fedora, but maybe try updating `adb` and `fastboot` following [this post on Ask Fedora](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/t/fastboot-package-for-fedora33-rooting-smartphone/14497/8)?

Comment: @AndrewT. I installed the android-tools package and used the `adb` binary from it but I get exactly the same problem.